# Exibir e manter submenu com JQuery

Tags: jquery, html5

Estou fazendo um submenu e quando passo o mouse numa opção mostra uma `div` com diversas opções, daí fiz um `mouseout` na classe dessa `div` para esconder ela mas a questão é que ela some mesmo navegando dentro dela.

Segue o código para quem poder ajudar:

```js
$("#marcas_menu").mouseover(function(){
  $('.marcas').css({'display':'block'});
})

$(".marcas").mouseout(function(){
  $('.marcas').css({'display':'none'});
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <div class="marcas"> 
    <div class="femininos">
    <div class="border_tab"><h4>Femininos</h4></div>   
   <div>
    <ul>
    <li>Lorem lpsum</li>
    <li>Lorem lpsum</li>
    <li>Lorem lpsum</li>
    <li>Lorem lpsum</li>
    <li>Lorem lpsum</li>
    <li>Lorem lpsum</li>
    <li>Lorem lpsum</li>
    <li>Lorem lpsum</li>
    <li>Lorem lpsum</li>
   </ul> 
   <a href="#">Ver Todos</a> 
   </div>     
  </div>

  <div class="masculinos">
  <div class="border_tab"><h4>Masculinos</h4></div>
     <div>
    <ul>
    <li>Lorem lpsum</li>
    <li>Lorem lpsum</li>
    <li>Lorem lpsum</li>
    <li>Lorem lpsum</li>
    <li>Lorem lpsum</li>
    <li>Lorem lpsum</li>
    <li>Lorem lpsum</li>
    <li>Lorem lpsum</li>
    <li>Lorem lpsum</li>
   </ul> 
   <a href="#">Ver Todos</a>
   </div> 
  </div>

  <div class="infantis">
  <div class="border_tab"><h4>Infantis</h4></div>
     <div>
    <ul>
    <li>Lorem lpsum</li>
    <li>Lorem lpsum</li>
    <li>Lorem lpsum</li>
    <li>Lorem lpsum</li>
    <li>Lorem lpsum</li>
    <li>Lorem lpsum</li>
    <li>Lorem lpsum</li>
    <li>Lorem lpsum</li>
    <li>Lorem lpsum</li>
   </ul>
   <a href="#">Ver Todos</a> 
   </div>  
  </div>

  <div class="imagem_aqui"></div>
  
 </div> <!-- fim marcas -->
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se `#marcas` está fora de `#marcas_menu` então quando mexe o rato para ficar em cima de `#marcas` já não está em `#marcas_menu` e por isso fecha. Uma solução simples é colocar o html de `#marcas` dentro de `#marcas_menu`

Comment: no caso #marcas_menu esta na LI marcas ainda estou tentando algo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troque o `mouseout` por `mouseleave`.

> O `mouseout` é acionado quando o cursor sai de qualquer *elemento-filho*
>   ou do próprio elemento. Já o `mouseleave` só é acionado quando o cursor
>   sai do elemento todo.

Comment: deu certo! obrigado!